# Как ограничить количество создаваемых элементов в RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Создал Activity с RecyclerView на основном экране. Заполнил данными из тестового строкового массива. Все выводится на экран. Далее при нажатии на FloatButton должен создаваться новый элемент - поэтому в обработчике добавляю новый элемент в массив и сообщаю об этом RecyclerView (recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();)
Теперь возникла необходимость, чтобы при достижении лимита (пусть будет 40 элементов), заменять старые элементы новыми.
Сейчас новые элементы просто добавляются вниз. Я не понимаю, как увидеть, что старые элементы заменены на новые (они что, должны появиться сверху, вместо 0-го элемента?).
И как же все-таки сделать это ограничение?
Главный метод

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ArrayList<String> data;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        data = new ArrayList();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            data.add("Title #" + i);
        }

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rview_list);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        final ListAdapter listAdapter = new ListAdapter(this);
        listAdapter.setData(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

        findViewById(R.id.btn_addData).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                System.out.println("Click!");
                int curItem = data.size();
                data.add("Added Title #"+ curItem);
                recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
```

Класс адаптера

```
private static class ListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList<String> mData;
private final int limit = 25;

public ListAdapter(final Context context) {
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public void setData(final ArrayList<String> data) {
    mData = data;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup parent, final int viewType) {
    final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.view_list_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.titleTextView.setText(mData.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mData == null ? 0 : mData.size();
}

class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public TextView titleTextView;

    public ViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        titleTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.view_title);
    }
}
```

Comment: а при чем тут RecyclerView? Это обычная логика.
Проверяете размер data, и если он больше 19, то перед добавлением удаляете первый элемент.

Comment: В задании дано при достижение лимита (пусть будет 25 элементов), заменять старые элементы новыми. Я так понимаю, что на месте старых (например 0, 1,...) должны появиться новые добавленные???

Comment: двоякая формулировка. В моем понимании, это наподобие очереди типа FIFO с размеров 25. Но под эту же формулировка подойдет и ваше описание, когда именно на место старых нужно вставлять новое. Разница лишь в том, что в моем случае, новые элементы всегда будут стоять в конце, а в вашем именно на месте старого. Так что лучше уточните задание

Comment: Уточнил задание. Новые элементы должны появляться в начале, заменяя старые: Added item #41 Item #2 ... Added item # 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых убираем notifyDataSetChanged. У вас датасет не изменяется, вы в старый добавляете элементы.

Весь инструментарий у вас уже есть, просто включаем императивную логику:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    System.out.println("Click!");
    if(data.size() == 40){
        data.remove(0);
        recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRemoved(0);
    }
    int curItem = (new Random()).nextInt();
    data.add("Added Title #"+ curItem);
    recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemInserted (data.size()-1);
}
```